# php code for a response to a curl post request

Tags: php, curl

I am new to cURL and I am setting up a test environment to send a cURL POST request using PHP and then I need to mimic the server (responding) program (PHP also) with a status code and payload. After looking and reading up on cURL and corresponding documentation and pertinent RFC documents there are a lot of examples on the request side but I could find no pertinent examples for the response side. My request code is as follows:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/curlresponder.php';  
              $fields =  array(
                   'City'            => urlencode('Hokeywaka'),
                   'State'           => urlencode('IL'),
                   'Zip'             => urlencode('60677'),
              );
              foreach($fields as $key => $value)
                     {$fields_string .= $key . "=" . $value . '&';}
                     rtrim($fields_string, '&');

              $ch = curl_init();

              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

              $result = curl_exec($ch);

              curl_close($ch);
              if  ($result === FALSE)
                  {echo 'Return failure ' . '<br />';
              else
                  {Process $result;}
```

Now I need to know what the responding program code is - assuming the request is received and processed successfully the response code of 200 is to be sent back with a payload attached (which I gather is also POST since the request was POST.

Comment: Just put the response code in whatever file is at http://localhost/curlresponder.php ...?

Answer (score 0):

You just need the remote page to post back a JSON script. And by Post back I just mean echo a JSON string on the page. You can use that in your $result var. You might want to create an API access key just to make sure nobody else uses it if you think there might be a security issue.

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($result,true);
if ($result['status']=="ok"){
    echo "Good request";
}else{
    echo "Bad request";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function curl_getinfo to obtain the info you wanted,and code like this

```
<?php
// Create a cURL handle

$ch = curl_init('http://www.stackoverflow.com/');

// Execute
curl_exec($ch);

// Check HTTP status code
if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
  switch ($http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) {
    case 200:  # OK
      break;
    default:
      echo 'Unexpected HTTP code: ', $http_code, "\n";
  }
}

// Close handle
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: It would be better if you elaborated more on your answer, instead of just mentioning a possible solution and linking to it; why not write a short snippet where you show the use of that function?

Comment: sorry , i just think it's the basic function , and the link page has some test code . sorry